# How can I see only changed lines in file with SmartGit?

Tags: sourcetree, smartgit

I'm seeing full file with highlighted lines. But I want to see only changed lines as in SourceTree. SourceTree displays only changed lines and it very comfortable. I must not scroll all file to find changes.

Can I tune SmartGit for it?

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

SmartGit 17.1 supports this - it's called "Compact Change Display".

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible in SmartGit.

But there are several ways to get to the changes quickly.

You can use the arrow buttons on the right or its shortcuts F6 and SHIFT+F6.

Or you can move the mouse between the two view and then using the mouse wheel. When the mouse is located at this area, scrolling will take you directly to the next change instead of just some lines up/down (see red markings in attached screenshot)

[image]