# Enable "Compact Change Display" in Smartgit

Tags: smartgit

I am referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782470/how-can-i-see-only-changed-lines-in-file-with-smartgit). Like written in the answer there is a  "Compact Change Display" but I cannot find it.

How can I enable or find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under the "hamburger" menu (three horizontal stripes) of the Changes panel:

[image]